# Readiness probe issues on aks with helm elasticsearch installation

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

i am trying to install via helm elasticsearch on an azure aks
this is the helm repo command :

```
helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co
```

this is my values.yaml :

```
clusterName: "elasticsearch"
nodeGroup: "master"

# Elasticsearch roles that will be applied to this nodeGroup
# These will be set as environment variables. E.g. node.master=true
roles:
  master: "true"
  ingest: "true"
  data: "true"

#Kubernetes replica count for the StatefulSet
replicas: 1
clusterHealthCheckParams: 'wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s'
minimumMasterNodes: 1
# Allows you to add any config files in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
# such as elasticsearch.yml
esConfig: 
 elasticsearch.yml: |
   xpack.security.enabled: false

image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch"
imageTag: "7.12.0"
imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"

esJavaOpts: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m" 

resources: 
  requests:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "4Gi"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "4Gi"

networkHost: "0.0.0.0"

volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: elk-azurefile-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi    

persistence:
  enabled: true
  labels:
    # Add default labels for the volumeClaimTemplate of the StatefulSet
    enabled: false
  annotations: {}


protocol: http
httpPort: 9200
transportPort: 9300

sysctlVmMaxMapCount: 262144
```

note the :

```
clusterHealthCheckParams: 'wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s'
```

it has created a headless and a cluster-ip services successfully.wh

when I try to install it the pods go up the get an error :

```
Readiness probe failed: Waiting for elasticsearch cluster to become ready (request params: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" )
```

and then

```
Readiness probe errored: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to exec in container: container is in CONTAINER_EXITED state
```

full kubectl describe pods elasticsearch-master-0:

```
Name:         elasticsearch-master-0
Namespace:    elk-stack
Priority:     0
Node:         aks-large-26770588-vmss000000/10.224.0.6
Start Time:   Sat, 14 May 2022 12:21:56 +0300
Labels:       app=elasticsearch-master
              chart=elasticsearch
              controller-revision-hash=elasticsearch-master-79dc798b86
              release=elasticsearch
              statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=elasticsearch-master-0
Annotations:  configchecksum: d9df7552a0a018b2f9f12fc4e9f161c978aa773de39ccc7755dde7ddbe2ba92
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.47.6
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.47.6
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/elasticsearch-master
Init Containers:
  configure-sysctl:
    Container ID:  containerd://381ad5812106422583bef9d2a22fd20a859f8ea2b7f447ff769a78cf6f858643
    Image:         docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0
    Image ID:      docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch@sha256:4999c5f75c1d0d69754902d3975dd36875cc2eb4a06d7fdceaa8ec0e71a81dfa
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sysctl
      -w
      vm.max_map_count=262144
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Sat, 14 May 2022 12:21:56 +0300
      Finished:     Sat, 14 May 2022 12:21:56 +0300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-6mz7h (ro)
Containers:
  elasticsearch:
    Container ID:   containerd://a1f0c38c60f26368bc5cdbde890cb67eb0fb5d8e345e04f7496740124d830c17
    Image:          docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0
    Image ID:       docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch@sha256:4999c5f75c1d0d69754902d3975dd36875cc2eb4a06d7fdceaa8ec0e71a81dfa
    Ports:          9200/TCP, 9300/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Sat, 14 May 2022 12:34:36 +0300
      Finished:     Sat, 14 May 2022 12:34:53 +0300
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  7
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  4Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      1
      memory:   4Gi
    Readiness:  exec [bash -c set -e
# If the node is starting up wait for the cluster to be ready (request params: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" )
# Once it has started only check that the node itself is responding
START_FILE=/tmp/.es_start_file

# Disable nss cache to avoid filling dentry cache when calling curl
# This is required with Elasticsearch Docker using nss < 3.52
export NSS_SDB_USE_CACHE=no

http () {
  local path="${1}"
  local args="${2}"
  set -- -XGET -s

  if [ "$args" != "" ]; then
    set -- "$@" $args
  fi

  if [ -n "${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" ]; then
    set -- "$@" -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}"
  fi

  curl --output /dev/null -k "$@" "http://127.0.0.1:9200${path}"
}

if [ -f "${START_FILE}" ]; then
  echo 'Elasticsearch is already running, lets check the node is healthy'
  HTTP_CODE=$(http "/" "-w %{http_code}")
  RC=$?
  if [[ ${RC} -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "curl --output /dev/null -k -XGET -s -w '%{http_code}' \${BASIC_AUTH} http://127.0.0.1:9200/ failed with RC ${RC}"
    exit ${RC}
  fi
  # ready if HTTP code 200, 503 is tolerable if ES version is 6.x
  if [[ ${HTTP_CODE} == "200" ]]; then
    exit 0
  elif [[ ${HTTP_CODE} == "503" && "7" == "6" ]]; then
    exit 0
  else
    echo "curl --output /dev/null -k -XGET -s -w '%{http_code}' \${BASIC_AUTH} http://127.0.0.1:9200/ failed with HTTP code ${HTTP_CODE}"
    exit 1
  fi

else
  echo 'Waiting for elasticsearch cluster to become ready (request params: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" )'
  if http "/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" "--fail" ; then
    touch ${START_FILE}
    exit 0
  else
    echo 'Cluster is not yet ready (request params: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" )'
    exit 1
  fi
fi
] delay=10s timeout=5s period=10s #success=3 #failure=3
    Environment:
      node.name:                             elasticsearch-master-0 (v1:metadata.name)
      cluster.initial_master_nodes:          elasticsearch-master-0,
      discovery.seed_hosts:                  elasticsearch-master-headless
      cluster.name:                          elasticsearch
      network.host:                          0.0.0.0
      cluster.deprecation_indexing.enabled:  false
      ES_JAVA_OPTS:                          -Xms512m -Xmx512m
      node.data:                             true
      node.ingest:                           true
      node.master:                           true
      node.ml:                               true
      node.remote_cluster_client:            true
    Mounts:
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml from esconfig (rw,path="elasticsearch.yml")
      /usr/share/elasticsearch/data from elasticsearch-master (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-6mz7h (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  elasticsearch-master:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  esconfig:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      elasticsearch-master-config
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-6mz7h:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  17m                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned elk-stack/elasticsearch-master-0 to aks-large-26770588-vmss000000
  Normal   Pulled     17m                kubelet            Container image "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    17m                kubelet            Created container configure-sysctl
  Normal   Started    17m                kubelet            Started container configure-sysctl
  Warning  Unhealthy  16m (x2 over 16m)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Waiting for elasticsearch cluster to become ready (request params: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" )
Cluster is not yet ready (request params: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s" )
  Normal   Created    15m (x4 over 17m)    kubelet  Created container elasticsearch
  Normal   Started    15m (x4 over 17m)    kubelet  Started container elasticsearch
  Warning  Unhealthy  15m                  kubelet  Readiness probe errored: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to exec in container: container is in CONTAINER_EXITED state
  Normal   Pulled     14m (x5 over 17m)    kubelet  Container image "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.0" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    119s (x60 over 16m)  kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
```

logs of container:

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-14T16:22:42,172Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-master-0, elasticsearch-master-1, elasticsearch-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-14T16:22:52,173Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-master-0, elasticsearch-master-1, elasticsearch-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-14T16:22:53,476Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "r.suppressed", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "path: /_cluster/health, params: {wait_for_status=green, timeout=200s}", 
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: null",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:297) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:345) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:263) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:660) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:718) [elasticsearch-7.17.3.jar:7.17.3]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]"] }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-14T16:23:02,175Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-master-0, elasticsearch-master-1, elasticsearch-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-14T16:23:12,176Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-master-0, elasticsearch-master-1, elasticsearch-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-14T16:23:22,177Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-master-0, elasticsearch-master-1, elasticsearch-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-14T16:23:32,178Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-master-0, elasticsearch-master-1, elasticsearch-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0" }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-14T16:23:42,180Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-master-0", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible nodes [elasticsearch-master-0, elasticsearch-master-1, elasticsearch-master-2] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}]; discovery will continue using [] from hosts providers and [{elasticsearch-master-0}{hchEvQdFQrW0sNFcB1Trew}{QsHcqMzFT7ibSJ1iDPK1pQ}{10.244.47.18}{10.244.47.18:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}] from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted version 0 in term 0" }
```

Comment: share the logs of pod which is not ready